# Zillow API Error:"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, api

I am attempting to pull some Zillow data from XML but am having trouble loading the XML.  My code is as follows (I replaced the API key with API KEY in URL):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.ajax({
url: "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=API KEY&address=10608+floral+park+lane&citystatezip=20878",
dataType: 'xml',
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);

}

});

</script>
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=API
>   KEY&address=10608+floral+park+lane&citystatezip=20878. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http:// WEBSITE DOMAIN' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Could anybody point me in the right direction / tell me what exactly is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a cross domain request - you're only allowed to request resources from your own domain.

Zillow doesn't support a JavaScript API so you would need to create your own server-side service that queries it (forwards the query) and sits on the same domain as your HTML page. Then you can call it (as a proxy).

Comment: This makes sense.  Do you happen to have a link to any tutorials or examples of this?  I'm clearly a noob and have failed at googling this for myself.

Comment: Try this (step 4): http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html#proxy