# Unable to get the xml response from zillow api webservice which is called from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, zillow

I'm trying to call the zillow api webservice url from angular js.

The following is my source code :

```
$http.get('http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetZestimate.htm?zws-id=<ZWSID>&zpid=48749425').success(function(response) {
                                alert(response) ;
                                console.log(response);
                            });
```

It is giving the following error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetZestimate.htm?zws-id=<ZWSID>&zpid=48749425.No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access
```

Please anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.!

Comment: See this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889011/zillow-api-errorno-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present

Answer (score 1):

From this Link :
[Zillow API Error:"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889011/zillow-api-errorno-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Zillow doesn't support a JavaScript API so we would need to create own server-side service that queries it (forwards the query) and sits on the same domain as our HTML page.

The following post gives the full code using java

[How to send data to an API call and get it back, using zillow.com API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090659/how-to-send-data-to-an-api-call-and-get-it-back-using-zillow-com-api)